# SQL Postgres Invalidate Rows that reference invalid Id's

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will invalidate rows that contain id references of an id in another table. The catch is that the rows to be invalidated contain groupings of these id's stored as a comma separated string. Let's take a look at the tables:

```
table_a            table_b
+----+------+      +---------+-------+
| id | name |      | ids     | valid |
+----+------+      +---------+-------+
|  1 |  a   |      | 1,2,3   |   T   |
|  2 |  b   |      | 4,3,8   |   T   |
|  3 |  c   |      | 5,2,5,4 |   T   |
|  4 |  d   |      | 7       |   T   |
|  5 |  e   |      | 6,8     |   T   |
|  6 |  f   |      | 9,7,2   |   T   |
|  7 |  g   |      +---------+-------+
|  8 |  h   |
+----+------+
```

Above you can see that `table_b` contains groupings of ids from `table_a` and as you can imagine the `table_a.id` is an `integer` while `table_b.ids` is `text`. The goal is to look at each `table_b.ids` and if it contains an id that does not exist in `table_a.id` then set its validity to `false`.

I have not worked with any `SQL` in quite sometime and I have never worked with `PostgreSQL` which is why I am having such difficulty. The closest query I could come up with, is not working, but is along the lines of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION cleanup_records() AS $func$
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_b
    SET valid = FALSE
    WHERE COUNT(
        SELECT regexp_split_to_table(table_b.ids) 
        EXCEPT SELECT id FROM table_a
    ) > 0;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The general idea is that I am trying to turn each row of `table_b.ids` into a table and then using the `EXCEPT` operator against `table_a` to see if it has any ids that are `invalid`. The error I receive is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: ...able_b SET valid = FALSE WHERE COUNT(SELECT reg...
```

which is not very helpful as it just indicates that I do not have the correct syntax. Is this query viable? If so can you show me where I may have gone wrong - if not is there an easier or even more complicated way to achieve this?

Sample data:

---

```
CREATE TABLE table_b
(ids text, valid boolean);

INSERT INTO table_b
(ids, valid)
VALUES
('1,2,3'   ,  'T'),
('4,3,8'   ,  'T'),
('5,2,5,4' ,  'T'),
('7'       ,  'T'),
('6,8'     ,  'T'),
('9,7,2'   ,  'T');

CREATE TABLE table_a
(id integer, name text);

INSERT INTO table_a
(id, name)
VALUES
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d'),
(5,'e'),
(6,'f'),
(7,'g'),
(8,'h');
```

Comment: In future please provide your sample data in a form that's easily turned into a SQL table. CREATE TABLE and INSERTs is nice, but otherwise at least a table that http://sqlfiddle.com/ knows how to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> groupings of these id's stored as a comma separated string

Don't do that. It's really bad database design, and is why you're having problems. See:

- [Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17808/7788)
- [PostgreSQL list of integers separated by comma or integer array for performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788)

Also, there's a more efficient way to do your query than that shown by vkp. If you do it that way, you're splitting the string for every ID you're testing. There is no need to do that. Instead, join on a table of expanded ID lists.

Something like:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET valid = 'f'
FROM table_b b
CROSS JOIN regexp_split_to_table(b.ids, ',') b_ids(id)
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON (a.id = b_ids.id::integer)
WHERE table_b.ids = b.ids
  AND a.id IS NULL
  AND table_b.valid = 't';
```

You need to join on `table_b` even though it's the update target because you can't make a lateral function reference to the update target table directly.

Comment: It's very bad database design although it is a sample representing an in production db, I should have mentioned. thanks for the links though - some very interesting reading!

Comment: Just a question here - what is the `AND a.id IS NULL` line doing here?

Comment: It filters out rows where the left join condition matched. So it only keeps rows where there is no corresponding b.ids entry for the a.id.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_b
SET valid = FALSE
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT regexp_split_to_table(table_b.ids) 
    EXCEPT SELECT id FROM table_a
);
```

You can use 'exists' to check for the existence of a row. The previous syntax was incorrect as `count`  can't be used that way.